# Char cannot be dereferenced? using compareTo

Tags: java, compareto

I'm trying to make a program that will read in a string and compare each character in the string to see if it is in alphabetical order.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void Main ( String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("#Please enter the string: ");
        String s = BIO.getString();

        while(!s.equals("END")){
            int length = s.length();
            String sLC = s.toLowerCase();
            int count = 0;
            boolean inOrder = true;

            for(int i = 0; i < length - 1 ; i++){
                if(sLC.charAt(i).compareTo(sLC.charAt(i+1)) > 0) {
                    inOrder = false;
                    break;
                }   
            }  

            System.out.println("#Please enter the string: ");  
            s = BIO.getString();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using blueJ and when I try to compile this it is giving me the error 'char cannot be dereferenced and highlighting the 'compareTo' method in my IF statement?

Comment: Special case of [java - compareTo with primitives -> Integer / int - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150446/compareto-with-primitives-integer-int)

Answer (score 6):

`.charAt()` returns a `char`, which is a primitive. It does not have a `.compareTo()` method.

`char` behaves much like a (smaller) `int`; use the following instead:

```
if(sLC.charAt(i) > sLC.charAt(i+1)) {
```

Comment: I think you want a >, not a <.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yup, thanks. I initially thought he wanted it to evaluate to `true`, not `false`.

Comment: ...except this would not be what OP wants if he wanted case insensitivity. For that you must raise back to the `Character` wrapper, if I remember correctly, because there's a spot in the library dedicated to Unicode-aware lexicographical sorting.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The OP calls `String sLC = s.toLowerCase();` before he starts the loop. In terms of accents and such, yeah, these would be exceptions.

Comment: @Eric ah ok thankyou so because I'm using a string method to compare two char types it is giving me this error :) I wasn't aware you could just use the > symbol to compare char types...

Comment: @Eric Indeed you are right. Except if OP would happen to be Georgian, as it just so happens that one must actually convert to **uppercase** in order to reliably conflate all same letters. There's special code that checks it that way to be seen in the `Character` source code, with the comment "this is really needed only for the Georgian characters".

Comment: Correction: actually it's the other way round, `toUpperCase` is the norm and `toLowerCase` is the exceptional case. And it's in the [String class, `equalsIgnoreCase`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#1401).

Answer (score 3):

`sLC.charAt(i)` gives you primitive char. And you cannot invoke `compareTo` on primitives. You need to wrap it in a Character wrapper object, or just use `comparison operator`.

```
if(Character.valueOf(sLC.charAt(i)).compareTo(
   Character.valueOf(sLC.charAt(i+1))) > 0)
```

or simply: -

```
if(sLC.charAt(i) > sLC.charAt(i+1))
```