# Overriding equals method to accept doubles inside of Object class. Java

Tags: java, object, boolean, double

I seem to be having an issue when comparing doubles inside of an equals method. I receive an error saying `java.lang.ClassCastException: and java.lang.Double` cannot be cast to Item. Am I not casting correctly? When I change the cast to Double I recieve the error `cannot find symbol - method getPrice().`

```
public class Item implements Comparable
{
    private String name, category;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    public Item(String nam,String cate,int quant,double pric)
    {
        name = nam;
        category = cate;
        quantity = quant;
        price = pric;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + ", " + category + ", " + quantity + ", " + price;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if (price <= ((Item)other).getPrice()) // Error //
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCategory()
    {
        return category;
    }

    public int getQuantity()
    {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return  price;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object other)
    {
        int result;

        double otherPrice = ((Item)other).getPrice();
        String otherCategory = ((Item)other).getCategory();

        if (this.equals(otherPrice))
            result = category.compareTo(otherCategory);
        else
            result = price > otherPrice ? + 1 : price < otherPrice ? -1 : 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Item.equals casts the passed Object to Item, but you call it with a Double, which can't be cast to anything except Number and Object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java for how to correctly implement equals and related issues.

Comment: @AngularLover that won't help... Java autoboxes anyways.

Comment: Why is this question being asked twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550438/double-cannot-be-dereferenced-for-equals-and-compareto-java

Answer (score 0):

I assume that other being passed into the compareTo mehtod is an Item.

So you have a Item other, and a double otherPrice.

Then when you call `this.equals(otherPrice)` in the if statement you are doing a Item.equals(Double).

You should be passing in an item. I think you want to replace `double otherPrice = ((Item)other).getPrice();` with `ObjectotherPrice = ((Item)other);`

See if you pass a double into the equals method you try and cast the double to a Item, witch is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Beware that the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method in Java takes an `Object` as argument. This is also true for the [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method. That means that the argument can be of *any* type (String, List, Double...). I suspect this is what is happening here.

In your `equals` method, you cast the argument `other` to `Item`. But what if `other` is not an `Item` ?

You should check the type of `other` before casting with the [instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) operator, like this :

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceof Item)) { //this also includes the case where other is null
        return false;
    }
    return price <= ((Item)other).getPrice();
}
```

The best practice would also be to add a check on `this` so as to avoid the cast altogether :

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(other instanceof Item)) {
        return false;
    }
    return price <= ((Item)other).getPrice();
}
```

With this in mind, you should also review your `compareTo` method.

Comment: I like this advice, very true. I think the real issue here is that he is passing a double into the equals method, then casting it to a Item.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in your compareTo method. You are trying to compare your Item Object to a double.
Your method should look like this:

```
public int compareTo(Object other) {
    int result;

    double otherPrice = ((Item) other).getPrice();
    String otherCategory = ((Item) other).getCategory();

    if (this.price==otherPrice)
        result = category.compareTo(otherCategory);
    else
        result = price > otherPrice ? +1 : price < otherPrice ? -1 : 0;
    return result;
}
```