# Can I use compareTo to sort integer and double values?

Tags: java

Can I use compareTo to sort integer and double values? My system gives me an error that I Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int. any ideas?

Code:

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {  
Record o1C = (Record)o1;
Record o2C = (Record)o2;                
return o1C.getPrice().compareTo(o2C.getPrice());
}

class Record
    public class Record {
    String name;
    int price;    

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the error message: `int` is a primitive, and therefore not an object. The `compareTo` method only works on objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compareTo with primitives -> Integer / int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150446/compareto-with-primitives-integer-int)

Answer (score 25):

Well, the compiler's right :) You can't call `compareTo` directly. However, depending on the version of Java you're using, you can use [`Integer.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) (introduced in 1.7) and [`Double.compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29) (introduced in 1.4).

For example:

```
return Integer.compare(o1C.getPrice(), o2C.getPrice());
```

If you're not on 1.7 and still want to use built-in methods, you *could* use:

```
Integer price1 = o1C.getPrice();
Integer price2 = o2C.getPrice();
return price1.compareTo(price2);
```

... but this will use unnecessary boxing. Given that sorting a large collection can perform really quite a lot of comparisons, that's not ideal. It may be worth rewriting `compare` yourself, until you're ready to use 1.7. It's dead simple:

```
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return x < y ? -1
         : x > y ? 1
         : 0;
}
```

Comment: public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return x - y;
}

Comment: @Deepak: Absolutely not. That would be a broken implementation when `y` is a very large positive number and `x` is a very large negative number, due to overflow.

Comment: How do I use the static method? Can you add code to support that using price1 & price2?

Comment: @summers: You call the static method with the two prices, and the return value is the comparison... what problems have you had trying it?

Comment: Like; 'Integer price1 = o1C.getPrice();
Integer price2 = o2C.getPrice();
return compare(price1, price2);'

Comment: @summers: Right - so what went wrong when you tried that?

Comment: Works now. I'd made a typo back then.

Answer (score 14):

Change the code

```
int price;
```

to

```
Integer price;
```

because primitive types such as `int` will not support any methods, like `compareTo()`.

Answer (score 2):

In your current code; easier solution would be to just change this line and all will be good:

```
return o1C.getPrice() - o2C.getPrice() ;
```

This would work fine and good performance too because method compare() has only following requirement viz. return zero if both values are equal; else a positive/negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Sort list by last name (for String values)

```
Collections.sort(peopleList, (p1, p2) -> 
                     p1.getLastName().compareTo(p2.getLastName()));
```

Step 2: Print all elements in the list

```
for (People ppl : peopleList) {
    System.out.print(ppl.getFirstName()+" - "+ppl.getLastName());
}
```

Step 1: Sort list by Age (for int values)

```
Collections.sort(peopleList, (p1, p2) -> p1.getAge() - (p2.getAge()));
```

Step 2: Print all elements in the list

```
for (People ppl : peopleList) {
    System.out.println(ppl.getAge());
}
```