# Comparator compare method() int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java, compiler-errors, integer, comparator, dereference

I'm doing some assignment work and I've struck a problem.

I've been given this example code:

```java
public class PersonNameComparator implements Comparator<Person>{
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        int retValue = p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
        if (retValue != 0)
            return retValue;
        else if (p1.getAge() < p2.getAge())
            return -1;  
        else if (p1.getAge() > p2.getAge())
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to do this, this happens:

```java
public class DVDComparator implements Comparator <DVD> {
     
    public int compare(DVD d1,DVD d2)
        {       
         int stars1 = d1.getNoOfStars().compareTo(d2.getNoOfStars());
         //ERROR - int cannot be dereferenced.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compareTo with primitives -> Integer / int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150446/compareto-with-primitives-integer-int)

Answer (score 6):

You get this error message since getNoOfStars() returns a primitive int and there is no method compareTo() defined for primitive types.

If you're using Java SE 7 you can use something like this:

```
public class DVDComparator implements Comparator <DVD> {

    public int compare(DVD d1,DVD d2){       
        return Integer.compare(d1.getNoOfStars(), d2.getNoOfStars());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call a method to compare primitive `int`s.  In fact, as you've discovered, you can't.

Just use the normal `<`, `>`, and `==` operators to compare `int`s.

Just make sure to follow the [contract of `compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) -- return an `int` less than 0, equal to 0, or greater than `0`, if `d1` is "less than" `d2`, if `d1` is "equal to" `d2`, or `d1` is "greater than" `d2`, respectively.

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Answer (score 2):

`int` being a primitive is not an object and thus does not have any methods. So when you try and call `.compareTo` on it, you get an error.

To compare ints, you can use the standard comparison operators `< > ==`,  *or* you could wrap it in an `Integer` Object and use the compare method as you are doing now. Although the former is favorable.

Answer (score 1):

// If Person.getName() returns a string then you could simply do the following to    // implement Comparable:

```
public class PersonNameComparator implements Comparator<Person>{
   public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
    return p1.getName() - p2.getName();       // It's the ninja way to do it
   }
}
```

Comment: *"If Person.getName() returns a string then you could simply do the following to ..."* create a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the reason for above error through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178539/can-i-use-compareto-to-sort-integer-and-double-values) link.
You can use one of following approaches which are simple to understand. (sorting in ascending order)

```
    if(d1.getNoOfStars() != d2.getNoOfStars())
    return d1.d1.getNoOfStars() - d2.getNoOfStars();
```

or

```
    if(d1.getNoOfStars() != d2.getNoOfStars())
    return d1.d1.getNoOfStars() > d2.getNoOfStars() ? 1 : -1;
```