# Comparator - int cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

I saw an example on here how to sort an ArrayList using the Comparator interface, so I tried it out. With Strings it worked perfectly, but with one variable that I want to sort being an Integer, it will not compile, saying *"int cannot be dereferenced"*.

What can I do so that this will work and allow me to sort an ArrayList by the score variable?

Here's my code:

```java
public class ScoreComparator implements Comparator<Review> {
    
    @Override
    public int compare(Review o1, Review o2)
    {
       return o1.getScore().compareTo(o2.getScore());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you're using to actually call the sort function.

Comment: int is a primitive type, it does not implement any Object methods.

Comment: @DwB Oh hi. Are you prepared to admit you were wrong about the Monty Hall problem yet?

Comment: @Boann If by "wrong" you mean "100% correct", then yes.  Otherwise, learn math you idiot.

Comment: o1.getScore() is returning int instead of Integer,possibly because of autoboxing/unboxing thing..that is the reason you are getting dereferencing error

Comment: @DwB <3 you too. I'd like to learn the math but to do that I need you to go back and answer the question I put to you on July 3rd. If you're so sure you're right you have nothing to be afraid of by answering it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use compareTo to sort integer and double values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178539/can-i-use-compareto-to-sort-integer-and-double-values)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't call methods on `int`s; there's no `compareTo` method to call.  That would be on the boxed `Integer` type, but boxing would be overkill.

If you're on Java 7+, you should write

```
return Integer.compare(o1.getScore(), o2.getScore());
```

...otherwise you'll more or less need to write

```
if (o1.getScore() < o2.getScore()) {
   return -1;
} else if (o1.getScore() > o2.getScore()) {
   return 1;
} else {
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or if `getScore()` returns an `int`, you can `return o1.getScore() - o2.getScore();`

Comment: This is correct, but it fails to explain why he gets the _int cannot be dereferenced_ error. I believe you should add this part to your answer as well.

Comment: @Jashaszun Careful: That works generally, but is unsafe for large values as the subtraction would overflow.

Comment: @Jashaszun This is simple and appropriate in *many* cases. But one should at least *mention* the possible over/underflow... (EDIT: Boann beat my by a few seconds ....)

Comment: @Boann That's a good point, but I doubt that for reviews of things the scores would be that large (or small).

Comment: This actually works better than the rest. I switched the < and > in the two statements and I got the order I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `Integer.compare` you could also use `Integer.valueOf(x).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(y))` which has been there since Java 1.2.  (Code plagiarized from the javadoc.)

Comment: @ajb: Yes, but that'd be wastefully boxing.

Answer (score 1):

Fyi, although this doesn't answer your specific question about the int dereferencing error, in Java 8 you don't need the dedicated comparator class at all. You can simply write:

```
yourList.sort((r1, r2) -> Integer.compare(r1.getScore(), r2.getScore()));
```

or

```
yourList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Review::getScore));
```

both of which are much nicer ways to do it.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
public class ScoreComparator implements Comparator<Review> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Review o1, Review o2)
    {
         return (o1.getScore()<o2.getScore() ? -1 : (o1.getScore()==o2.getScore() ? 0 : 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution can lead to integer underflow or overflow and consequently wrong return codes! Wasserman's solution uses the recomended approach.

Comment: That does what I want, other than it sorts in the reverse order of what I'd like it to be at. Is there a way to change the order around? If not it's fine, I'm already ecstatic this fixes my main problem.

Comment: To change the order you need to invert the results, i.e. o2.getScore() - o1.getScore(). But as a previous poster said, this is dangerous as it may throw an exception.