# Android SQLiteDatabase at item from top

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I would like all new items to be added at the top, ie, if ROW-ID 1,2,3 are taken and I add a new item, it should be added at position 1, and rest should be shifted. But right now when I add an item, it gets added at ID 4 (ie at the back).

**Method**

```
Temp_Cover_StoryBaseList_DatabaseHandler db = new Temp_Cover_StoryBaseList_DatabaseHandler(context, currentUsername);
db.addStory(pointer, filePath);
db.close();
```

_

```
    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        String CREATE_STORIES_TABLE 
                = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEMP_BASESTORY_LIST 
                + "(" 
                + KEY_ID            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_POINTER       + " STRING,"
                + KEY_URI           + " STRING"
                + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_STORIES_TABLE);
    }
```

_

```
    // Adding new Story
    public void addStory(String pointer, String filePath) 
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_POINTER,  pointer  );
        values.put(KEY_URI,      filePath );

        // Inserting Row
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_TEMP_BASESTORY_LIST, null, values);
        Log.d(TAG, "TempCover ID:" + Long.toString(id));

        db.close(); 
    }
```

_

```
public List<StoryData> getAllStories()
{
    List<StoryData> storyDataList = new ArrayList<StoryData>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_STORIES_LIST;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if(cursor !=null)
    {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            do 
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> coverList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                coverList.add( cursor.getInt(4) );
                coverList.add( cursor.getInt(5) );

                StoryData sData = new StoryData
                        (
                        cursor.getInt(0),
                        cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getString(2),
                        cursor.getInt(3),
                        coverList,
                        Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(6)),
                        Boolean.parseBoolean(cursor.getString(7)),
                        cursor.getString(8)
                        );

                // Adding contact to list
                storyDataList.add(sData);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }


    return storyDataList;
}
```

Comment: You cannot ! instead Why don't you retrieve data in descending order ?

Comment: I've added the code for the method getAllStories() ; should I just use Collections.reverse(storyDataList); before returning the list; or is there another way? //@ShreeKrishna

Comment: SQL tables are not ordered; a query without ORDER BY can return the rows in any order. So what do you mean with "top"?

Comment: @summers No, I don't prefer that. You can sort by It's id in descending order in custom way.

Comment: Whats the method to sort it using ID? Could you share code? @ShreeKrishna

Comment: Do you have id property in `StoryData` class to store the value of id field from database ?

Comment: Yes I do  @ShreeKrishna

Comment: @summers I've added it as answer, feel free to ask if any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say simply, You cannot do so,

Directly using `Collections.reverse(storyDataList);` may not work so
I suggest getting all the data and sorting it with the `ID`, Like here using [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and creating custom class for sorting like

```
public class SortDataCompare implements Comparator<StoryData> {
    @Override
    public int compare(StoryData s1, StoryData s2) {
        return s1.getId().compareTo(s2.getId());
    }
}
```

And use The class like

```
Collections.sort(storyDataList, new SortDataCompare());
```

Then your `storyDataList` Will be sorted.

Comment: Just a note. Using this return gives a "Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int" : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14178549/2534694

Comment: @summers Thanks, I appreciate your note.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to change the autoincrement id of the SQL row. This is set automatically when you create a new row. You cannot, or at least should not, set the autoincrement id or depend on the physical order of rows in the table.

It is better practice to create a separate column that contains the desired order of rows as an integer. Then, when you query the table, you can sort the rows based on the integer in that column.

You could add the column as seen below:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        String CREATE_STORIES_TABLE 
                = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEMP_BASESTORY_LIST 
                + "(" 
                + KEY_ID            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_POINTER       + " STRING,"
                + KEY_URI           + " STRING,"
                + KEY_ORDER         + " INTEGER"
                + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_STORIES_TABLE);
    }
```

Now add the order when you insert the item. Just increment the value for order each time you insert a row:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_POINTER,  pointer  );
values.put(KEY_URI,      filePath );
values.put(KEY_ORDER,    order );

// Inserting Row
long id = db.insert(TABLE_TEMP_BASESTORY_LIST, null, values);
```

Comment: Nop. I just want to add new values at the top rather than the bottom

Comment: Why you insist on add as first row? You can always display the rows in any order. Let it be any Id, you can display it on top or bottom

Comment: Okay. But how do I use the KEY_ORDER property to reorder the ArrayList?

Comment: You can use the Collections class: Collections.sort(arrayList, comparator);