# "int cannot be dereferenced" in Java

Tags: java, int, bluej

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm using BlueJ. I keep getting this "Int cannot be dereferenced" error when trying to compile and I'm not sure what the problem is.  The error is specifically happening in my if statement at the bottom, where it says "equals" is an error and "int cannot be dereferenced." Hope to get some assistance as I have no idea what to do. Thank you in advance!

```
public class Catalog {
    private Item[] list;
    private int size;

    // Construct an empty catalog with the specified capacity.
    public Catalog(int max) {
        list = new Item[max];
        size = 0;
    }

    // Insert a new item into the catalog.
    // Throw a CatalogFull exception if the catalog is full.
    public void insert(Item obj) throws CatalogFull {
        if (list.length == size) {
            throw new CatalogFull();
        }
        list[size] = obj;
        ++size;
    }

    // Search the catalog for the item whose item number
    // is the parameter id.  Return the matching object 
    // if the search succeeds.  Throw an ItemNotFound
    // exception if the search fails.
    public Item find(int id) throws ItemNotFound {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < size; ++pos){
            if (id.equals(list[pos].getItemNumber())){ //Getting error on "equals"
                return list[pos];
            }
            else {
                throw new ItemNotFound();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to using a `int` where an `Integer`, `Number` or `Object` is expected...`int` does not have any methods

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`id` is of primitive type `int` and not an `Object`. You cannot call methods on a primitive as you are doing here :

```
id.equals
```

Try replacing this:

```
        if (id.equals(list[pos].getItemNumber())){ //Getting error on "equals"
```

with

```
        if (id == list[pos].getItemNumber()){ //Getting error on "equals"
```

Comment: What can I do if I need to use `Integer.compareTo`?

Comment: @RoyCohen [java - compareTo with primitives -> Integer / int - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150446/compareto-with-primitives-integer-int)

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you're trying to use `int` as if it was an `Object`, which it isn't (well...it's complicated)

```
id.equals(list[pos].getItemNumber())
```

Should be...

```
id == list[pos].getItemNumber()
```

Comment: One doubt: == compares reference for objects and compares values for primitives, right? Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. Primitives are special.

Comment: Actually studying interface I received this error and googling brought me to this answer. Kindly look if you can:

`error:int cannot be dereferenced`
   `System.out.println("A  = " + A.AB);`
                                 
The class in which SOP is called implements one `interface C` and A is super interface of C. int AB is defined in both interface. Error occurs at `A.AB`.

Comment: `int AB` can't be declared in any `interface`, it could only possibly be declared within a `class`...

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing is the process of accessing the value referred to by a reference . Since, int is already a value (not a reference), it can not be dereferenced.
so u need to replace your code (.) to(==).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `getItemNumber()` returns an `int`, replace

`if (id.equals(list[pos].getItemNumber()))`

with

`if (id == list[pos].getItemNumber())`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
id.equals(list[pos].getItemNumber())
```

to

```
id == list[pos].getItemNumber()
```

For more details, you should learn the difference between the primitive types like `int`, `char`, and `double` and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

As your methods an int datatype, you should use "==" instead of equals()

try replacing this 
    if (id.equals(list[pos].getItemNumber()))

with

```
if (id.equals==list[pos].getItemNumber())
```

it will fix the error .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error in the initialization of the Integer somewhere

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try

```
id == list[pos].getItemNumber()
```

instead of

```
id.equals(list[pos].getItemNumber()
```