# temp.compareTo error. Int cannot be be dereferenced

Tags: java, sorting, int, dereference

I am trying to create a program that sort five integers in ascending order. I have never ran into a dereferenced error before so I am curious what I am doing wrong.

```
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] a = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter integer # "+ 1 + i);
            int temp = input.nextInt();
            a[i] = temp;
        }


        System.out.println("Sorted from lowest to highest");


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                int temp = a[i];
                int tempB = a[j];
                if (temp.compareTo(tempB) < 0) {
                    a[i] = tempB;
                    a[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error on this line.

```
if (temp.compareTo(tempB) < 0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Special case of [java - compareTo with primitives -> Integer / int - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150446/compareto-with-primitives-integer-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp
```

is of type int, which does not have methods. you should just write

```
if(temp < tempB)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `compareTo` method on `int` (**primitive type**).

**Use:**

```
if(temp < tempB)
```