# Using arrayList int cannot be dereferenced on error java

Tags: java

I am getting an int cannot be dereferenced error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
public class ComparatorYearLevel implements Comparator<CourseDomain> {
    @Override
    public int compare(CourseDomain one, CourseDomain two) {
        return one.getYearLevel().compareTo(two.getYearLevel());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the meaning of the year level is, and what sorts of values it can take on?  How should we be logically comparing them?

Comment: Your getYearLevel might be returning primitive that is not an object which yield this error as you can only comapare objects using `compareTo` method

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
@Override
public int compare(CourseDomain one, CourseDomain two) {
    int a = one.getYearLevel();
    int b = two.getYearLevel();
    return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
}
```

You could also return this:

```
return Integer.compare(a, b);
```

But the ternary expression should perform better.

Further reading: [compareTo with primitives -> Integer / int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150446/compareto-with-primitives-integer-int)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that `one.getYearLevel()` is returning `int`.  Since that's not an object type, you can't go calling methods on it.

You could write

```
return Integer.valueOf(one.getYearLevel()).compareTo(two.getYearLevel());
```

This explicitly converts your `int` to and `Integer`, on which it is possible to call the `compareTo` method.

Another alternative would be just to write

```
return one.getYearLevel() - two.getYearLevel();
```

which meets the requirements of `compareTo`, provided the `int` values aren't large enough to risk integer overflow.