# Can I use the compareTo to compare two values of type int?

Tags: java, int, compareto

In this problem I want to compare the two variables int "a" and "b" with the compareTo, but there is an error. How can I fix it? Thank you for your support.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a=5;
    int b=5;
    if (a.compareTo(b));
}
```

This is the error: "Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int"

Comment: No, they are primitives, not objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [compareTo with primitives -> Integer / int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150446/compareto-with-primitives-integer-int)

Comment: The question is Why do you want to compare them that way if simple code like `a < b` will work just as fine and even be easier readable

Comment: Also, compareTo returns an int, not a boolean

Comment: What _error_? What didn't you understand about its message? Did you look up its message or better understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int` is one of the few *primitive* types that are built into the Java language, and as you noticed, primitives cannot contain methods.

You can wrap them in the non-primitive [`Integer` type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), which is a class, and then do the comparison:

```
Integer.valueOf(a).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b))
```

Better (because it doesn't create useless objects) is to use the static method that that class offers, which does take primitive `int`s as arguments:

```
Integer.compare(a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you tell me why this question was closed and no longer accepts answers? Thank you.

Comment: Probably because you initially didn't post the actual error message you were getting, and because a very similar (duplicate) question already exists as linked in the comment by @jhamon.